# Count number of elements in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to transform a `Source` of Scala entities into a `Source` of `ByteString` via Alpakka's `CsvFormatting` and count number of elements in the initial stream. Could you suggest the best way to count the `initialSource` elements and keep the result as a `ByteString` `Source`:

```
val initialSource: Source[SomeEntity, NotUsed] = Source.fromPublisher(publisher)
val csvSource: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = initialSource
  .map(e => List(e.firstName, e.lastName, e.city))
  .via(CsvFormatting.format())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To count the elements in a stream, one must run the stream. One approach is to broadcast the stream elements to two sinks: one sink is the result of the main processing, the other sink simply counts the number of elements. Here is a simple example, which uses a [graph](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-graphs.html#constructing-graphs) to obtain the materialized values of both sinks:

```
val sink1 = Sink.foreach(println)
val sink2 = Sink.fold[Int, ByteString](0)((acc, _) => acc + 1)

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink1, sink2)((_, _)) { implicit builder =>
  (s1, s2) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[ByteString](2))

  val source: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] =
    Source(1 to 10)
      .map(i => List(i.toString))
      .via(CsvFormatting.format())

  source ~> broadcast.in
  broadcast.out(0) ~> s1
  broadcast.out(1) ~> s2
  ClosedShape
}) // RunnableGraph[(Future[Done], Future[Int])]

val (fut1, fut2) = g.run()

fut2 onComplete {
  case Success(count) => println(s"Number of elements: $count")
  case Failure(_) =>
}
```

In the above example, the first sink just prints the stream elements and has a materialized value of type `Future[Done]`. The second sink does a fold operation to count the stream elements and has a materialized value of type `Future[Int]`. The following is printed:

```
ByteString(49, 13, 10)
ByteString(50, 13, 10)
ByteString(51, 13, 10)
ByteString(52, 13, 10)
ByteString(53, 13, 10)
ByteString(54, 13, 10)
ByteString(55, 13, 10)
ByteString(56, 13, 10)
ByteString(57, 13, 10)
ByteString(49, 48, 13, 10)
Number of elements: 10
```

---

Another option for sending stream elements to two different sinks, while retaining their respective materialized values, is to use [`alsoToMat`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#alsoToMat[Mat2,Mat3](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[Out],Mat2])(matF:(Mat,Mat2)=%3EMat3):FlowOpsMat.this.ReprMat[Out,Mat3]):

```
val sink1 = Sink.foreach(println)
val sink2 = Sink.fold[Int, ByteString](0)((acc, _) => acc + 1)

val (fut1, fut2) = Source(1 to 10)
  .map(i => List(i.toString))
  .via(CsvFormatting.format())
  .alsoToMat(sink1)(Keep.right)
  .toMat(sink2)(Keep.both)
  .run() // (Future[Done], Future[Int])

fut2 onComplete {
  case Success(count) => println(s"Number of elements: $count")
  case Failure(_) =>
}
```

This produces the same result as the graph example described earlier.